# Disable iCloud Photo Library on iOS device and keeping all photos and videos

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, photos

Somehow iCloud Photo Library was turned on unintentionally and I would like to disable iCloud Photo Library on my iOS device but retain all photos and videos on my iOS device in it's full resolution. How can I do this?

You can assume that I have the storage space on the iOS device.